# Image path not saving in Database column

Tags: php

**Background** :

I am uploading image in server through form....

[image]

**Issue** :

But Image path is not saving in Database....

**form.php**

```
<form name="save" id="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" >

<tr>    
<td class="jtd">Image:</td>
<td><input type="file" name="product_image" id="product_image"/>
<img src="<?php echo $row['product_image'];?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="Save"  onclick="validatesubproductform();" /></td>
</tr>

</form>
```

**script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function validatesubproductform()
      {
        var id='<?php echo $id?>';
        var imageflag = 1;
        var re = new RegExp("^[^<>%$&*#%@|]*$");
        var cproductimage = $("#product_image").val();
        var product_imagename=document.getElementById('product_image');
        if(cproductimage.length >1) {
            var extension = cproductimage.split('.').pop().toUpperCase();

          if (product_imagename.files && product_imagename.files[0])
          var size = product_imagename.files[0].size;          
          if(size==0) {imageflag = 0;alert("Image Is corrupted.");}
          if(re.test(product_imagename.files[0].name)===false)
            {
             imageflag=0;
             alert('please upload the file without special characters and SPACES');
             return false;
            }
             if (/\s/.test(product_imagename.files[0].name)) {
             imageflag=0;
              alert('The filename can not contain whitespace. Please rename the file.');
              return false;
            }   
        }

        if(imageflag == 1) { 
          $("#savejsonhomescreen").submit();
        }
        else {
             return false;
        }       
      }
</script>
```

**save.php**

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/html/mobile/phonecasejson/mobilecases/home_screen_img/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['product_image']['name']);

if(isset($_POST["productKey"]) && $_POST["productKey"]!=''){$updatefield=$updatefield.",product_key='".@$_POST["productKey"]."'";$insertColumn=$insertColumn.",product_key";$insertValue=$insertValue.",'".$_POST["productKey"]."'";}

if(isset($_FILES['product_image']['name']) && $_FILES['product_image']['name']!='')
    {       
        echo $uploadfileUrl='http://139.59.24.243/mobile/phonecasejson/mobilecases/home_screen_img/'.$_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
       { 
        $updatefield=$updatefield.",product_image='".$response."'";
        $insertColumn=$insertColumn.",product_image";
        $insertValue=$insertValue.",'".$response."'";
       }
    }

if(@$_POST['id']='')
{
echo $sql = "INSERT INTO json_homescreen (".$insertColumn.") VALUES (".$insertValue.")";    
    $result = $db_handle->executeUpdate($sql);
    $_SESSION['msg']="Record Saved Successfully1.";
    header("location:jsonhomescreen.php");
    die;
}
```

I am using mysqli , please let me know if you need any information....

Thanks in Advance....

I appreciate your help.... I tried lot before posting question here....

Comment: is the image stored?

Comment: @TobokSitanggang thanks for comment, yes image stored in server..... path : `/var/www/html/mobile/phonecasejson/mobilecases/home_screen_img`

Comment: form.php= https://pastebin.com/jw5PVR97 ,

save.php = https://pastebin.com/5kX6PFkX

Comment: @TobokSitanggang am i doing in wrong way ? is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: in some server u need to add `./` on path file. just try that

Comment: @TobokSitanggang sorry , i didt got , can you please tell me what code i need to modify in question ?

Comment: I don't see any reference to `$uploadfile ` in your SQL.

Comment: @Dave i am using this : `echo $sql = "INSERT INTO json_homescreen (".$insertColumn.") VALUES (".$insertValue.")";`

Comment: ohh im so sorry, im not focus on your qustion. did u want save image like ` path/imagename.png' in your db? just to verified

Comment: @TobokSitanggang thats right.... i want to save in column.....

Comment: I see what you are using @vickeycolors but I don't see any reference to the variable that contains the full path to your image in the `$insertValue` variable that you created.

Comment: @Dave  please check full code : https://pastebin.com/5kX6PFkX

Comment: I just did. Still no reference or mention of adding `$uploadfile` to your `$insertValue` variable. Unless I'm completely blind! I see you create it, create a URL using it then an unlink of it which appears to be commented out. At no point is it added to the values you are going to insert into the DB.

Comment: @Dave thanks , you read all the code, i thought this code will work : `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
       { 
        $updatefield=$updatefield.",product_image='".$response."'";
  $insertColumn=$insertColumn.",product_image";
  $insertValue=$insertValue.",'".$response."'";
       }` please tell me what changes i need ?

Comment: On line 12 you create a variable that has the full path. If you want the column named `product_image` to contain that path then you need to use the `$uploadfile` variable on lines 38 and 40 from what I can tell. For the life of me I can't see why you are using a variable named `$response` on those 2 lines.

Comment: @Dave thanks, now path is saving as `/var/www/html/mobile/phonecasejson/mobilecases/home_screen_img/127.jpg` , but i want to save as `http://139.59.24.243/mobile/phonecasejson/mobilecases/home_screen_img/127.jpg` please tell what changes i need to do ?

Comment: you dont need to change path `$uploaddir`. just use `$uploadfileUrl` on line 38

Comment: @Dave thanks a lot for you support..... i used `$insertValue=$insertValue.",'".$uploadfileUrl."'";`

Comment: @TobokSitanggang thanks a lot for you support..... i used `$insertValue=$insertValue.",'".$uploadfileUrl."'";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 12 you create a variable that has the full path. If you want the column named product_image to contain that path then you need to use the $uploadfile variable on lines 38 and 40. If you want to use the full URL instead of just the file path use the $uploadfileUrl variable.

Change line 40 to read:

```
$insertValue=$insertValue.",'".$uploadfileUrl."'";
```